# Timeouts in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a notifer component for my website. Basically one you hit say "add" and the item is "added" on the top of my website a green bar will come up and say "successfully created"

Now after a second I would like it to disappear. I am not sure what the best way to do this would be? Is it to have a javascript timer somewhere?

```
import React from 'react';

import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';

import 'materialize-css/js/materialize.js';
import classNames from 'classnames/index.js';

export default class Notifer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var notifcationClasses = classNames({
            'notifcation-success': this.props.notiferReducer.success,
            'notifcation-error': this.props.notiferReducer.error,
            'hide': !(this.props.notiferReducer.success || this.props.notiferReducer.error)
        });
        return (
            <div id="notifcation" className={notifcationClasses}>
                Sucessfully created
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Action

```
import {actions}  from './Actions.js';

export function setNotifer(success) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.SET_NOTIFIER, payload: success });
    };
}
```

Reducer

```
import { actions } from '../actions/Actions';

export default function NotiferReducer(state = {
    success: false,
    error: false
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SET_NOTIFIER: {
            return {
                success: action.payload,
                error: !action.payload
            };
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Normally I would use something like growl but I did not see anything for reactjs(well I did see some but none of them seemed to be very popular)

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);  Since you are asking the best way... I would put an OK button on the dialog.... especially the error dialog to make sure the user has enough time to read and comprehend it.

Comment: I would set a timeout in your action creator to trigger another action to close the view.

Comment: @riscarrott can you put an more of an example of this? Which action are you talking about the "add" action " or "notifier" action.

Comment: Why not use something that has this built in? Take a look at: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Answer (score 4):

As it looks like you're using redux-thunk I would set a timeout in your action creator to trigger another action to close the notification, e.g.

```
import {actions}  from './Actions.js';

export function setNotifer(success) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.SET_NOTIFIER, payload: success });
        setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: actions.CLOSE_NOTIFIER }), 1000) 
    };
}
```

Then your reducer would just nullify the success and error properties when it receives the `CLOSE_NOTIFIER` action.

This would keep your components synchronous and it's ultimately the same pattern commonly used when making ajax requests in redux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `setTimeout` to achieve this:

(*edit* I've updated the snippet to use `redux` and `redux-thunk`)

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;

const message = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_NOTIFICATION':
      return action.message;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const setNotification = (message, duration) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION', message: message});
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION', message: null});
  }, duration);
};


const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({message: message}),
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk.default)
);

class App extends Component {
      
  showMessage = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(
      setNotification('This message will self destruct in 3 seconds', 3000)
    );
  };

  render() {  
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.message && <div className="message">{this.props.message}</div>}
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.showMessage}>Click to show message</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App = connect(
  state => ({ message: state.message })
)(App);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.message {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/redux@3.5.2/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/redux-thunk@2.1.0/dist/redux-thunk.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-redux@4.4.5/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```